# How can I see what hats I've earned on a given site?

Tags: feature-request, winter-bash-2013, winter-bash-2014

On [the main Winter Bash page](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/), I can easily see which hats I've earned on at least one site.

How can I find out which hats I've earned on a given site? I'd have expected this to be visible in the hat popup on my profile, but all it gives me is the lists, and I need to click on each hat to see whether I've earned it on that particular site.

Comment: [Requested last year](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/213593/162102).

Comment: I see that the url that abby posted in the answer still work (changing 2013). Or are you asking for something else?

Comment: @Braiam That doesn't show the list of hats, only the first 9. Unless it's changed this year? And it would be more convenient to have it on the site itself, rather than have to find myself on the leaderboard.

Answer (score 7):

You can see your own Top 9 hats on the site in question's [leaderboard](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/meta.stackoverflow.com). (Get to any leaderboard by going to `http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/[SiteURL]`, or just by going to [the main leaderboard](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/leaderboard) and clicking the one you like best.)

That's about all we've got for now. It'd be a [feature-request] to get something more comprehensive (and you're welcome to request it).

Comment: [Ok, requested.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/211808/2)

Comment: Any chance to add hat data to [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/) so we can do our own queries on it?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212004/how-can-i-find-the-least-worn-hat/212009#212009

Comment: Still nothing this year?

Comment: A boat shop? here on meta, too? :P

Comment: Still nothing this year? (Is there an echo here?)

Answer (score 1):

This information exists on the hat rack, but it's not displayed in any way. There are already two different kinds of highlights (the hat you're wearing and the hat you've selected); adding a third would just be confusing. Even more so, *any* way of showing it means extra stuff on an already busy interface, and if we're honest, this information is mostly interesting for users who are a bit nostalgic for the 2012 Winter Bash rules.

So if someone feels like playing with user styles, look for the CSS class `wb-earned-here` on the hat rack. I added that class in the hope that we'd come up with a non-obtrusive way of showing this, but we haven't.

Comment: saw that just now. What about a red border or something like that?