# How can I find the least worn hat?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2013

How can I find out which hat is being worn the least among users? Any queries? What's the new table storing data about hats?

How can I get the number of users wearing a specific hat?

Comment: FWIW, even if there *were* a table for hats in the Data Explorer, there wouldn't be data in the table until Sunday because it's only updated once a week.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't think this is something we could realistically put in the data explorer. It would be a bit of a challenge because the event is very short-lived, and we'd have to do some interesting hackery to get the data into data explorer itself (creating the dump, dealing with the schema, etc).

However, I'll see if we can include some interesting data (most popular, least popular, most common, rarest, etc) when we wrap the event up in January.

Answer (score 11):

Last year there was a [wrap-up report posted on the SE blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/01/boxing-day/). We're planning to do the same this year, and the most common and rarest hats are good candidates for details to include.

Answer (score 1):

Don't need Data Explorer or fancy tools for this one :)

Clearly the autobots logo is the least worn hat.

[image: megatron]

Comment: How do we get it :) ?

Comment: @ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd - I have absolutely no clue at all :( Like, not even a guess or some obscure hint.

Comment: I don't mean to nitpick, but that's the autobots logo, not [Megatron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calvin_Johnson).

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi - Yes, apparently my tranformer-fu is not up to par today. I will edit the post.